# Share WiFi from Raspberry Pi 3 B+ to iPhone

Tags: wifi, connection

I want to share the WiFi from my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ to my iPhone but I don't know how. How can I achieve this?

Comment: it is not `pie`

Comment: For the raspberry pi part of the setup, you can look at this, if it helps [Setting up Raspberry Pi 3 as a WiFi beacon to be detected by an Android device](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56022/setting-up-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-beacon-to-be-detected-by-an-android-device)

Comment: Also this post about  [Raspi as a wifi access point](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8560/rpi-as-wifi-access-point-and-vpn-router?rq=1) seems relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup an access point on the Raspberry Pi so other devices can connect to it like to any other hotspot, e.g. a home internet router. There are a lot of tutorials out there how to do it. Just google for "*Raspberry Pi access point*" but don't use tutorials older than two years.

A tutorial from the Raspberry Pi Foundation you can find at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point in a standalone network (NAT)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md). It uses old technologies. If you like to use more up to date networking you can look at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866).